# Matplotlib, the lines in a line graph are too crowded

Tags: python, matplotlib

A line graph is generated by `matplotlib` as follows. The lines are too close and crowed from a certain steps due to their values, how can I make the difference among these lines clear:
[Line Graph by Matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us0du.png)

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
####data#####    
A = np.array([0.8325, 0.8847, 0.902, 0.9104, 0.917, 0.9197, 0.9248, 0.9296, 0.9338, 0.9374, 0.9393, 0.9415, 0.9441, 0.945, 0.9475, 0.95, 0.9522, 0.953, 0.9556, 0.9567,])
B = np.array([0.8702, 0.9012, 0.9118, 0.92, 0.9268, 0.9312, 0.9349, 0.9395, 0.9413, 0.9447, 0.9477, 0.9497, 0.9523, 0.9535, 0.9556, 0.9573, 0.9585, 0.9604, 0.9614, 0.9634])
C = np.array([0.8518, 0.8926, 0.9061, 0.914, 0.9201, 0.9241, 0.9271, 0.9321, 0.9347, 0.938, 0.9411, 0.9424, 0.9447, 0.9469, 0.9481, 0.9511, 0.9524, 0.9542, 0.9551, 0.9571,])
D = np.array([0.7114, 0.8093, 0.8616, 0.8877, 0.9024, 0.9114, 0.9156,  0.9194, 0.9258, 0.9298, 0.9341, 0.937, 0.9405, 0.9429, 0.9446, 0.9472, 0.9497, 0.9513, 0.9523, 0.9546])
#### plot#######
step = np.arange(1,21)
plt.plot(step, A, color='r', label='A')
plt.plot(step, B, linestyle='-', color='m', label='B')
plt.plot(step, C, linestyle='--', color='c', label='C')
plt.plot(step, D, linestyle='-.', color = 'k', label='D')
plt.xlabel('steps')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
#plt.title('')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can highlight the region of interest, plot it in an inset while keeping the complete curves as it is. Here is just the part to highlight and then plot the inset:

```
patch = patches.Rectangle((10,0.92),10.5,0.05,linewidth=1,linestyle='--',edgecolor='gray',facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(patch)
left, bottom, width, height = [0.3, 0.2, 0.57, 0.3]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])
ax2.plot(step[8:], A[8:], '-r')
ax2.plot(step[8:], B[8:], '-m')
ax2.plot(step[8:], C[8:], '--c')
ax2.plot(step[8:], D[8:], '-.k')
ax.plot([4.9, 10], [0.84, 0.92], '--', c='gray', lw=1)
ax.plot([21, 20.5], [0.84, 0.92], '--', c='gray', lw=1)
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: This is really nice!

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes, I am a newbie to stack overflow, sorry  for late accepting.

Answer (score -1):

When you have to display graphs close to each other, a common trick is to shift them vertically with respect to each other. But then, of course, it will be more difficult to notice subtle differences between them.

```
plt.plot(step, A, color='r', label='A')
plt.plot(step, B+.05, linestyle='-', color='m', label='B+.05')
plt.plot(step, C+.10, linestyle='--', color='c', label='C+.10')
plt.plot(step, D+.15, linestyle='-.', color = 'k', label='D+.15')
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. And I need to see the subtle differences between these lines.

Comment: Then I fear that you should (also) plot the differences like `A-B` or `A-average`, possibly, in an inset figure. It is in general too much to try to show large trends/variations and tiny features in the same graph.